# Absolute minimum difference

Tags: elementary-number-theory

We are given a sequence of positive numbers. We can perform two types of operations on these sequence of numbers.

- If number E is even, then we can replace it by E/2
- If number E is odd, then we can replace it by 2E

We have to find the minimum absolute difference between any two elements after performing these operations any number of times.

Example 1: let the sequence of numbers be 1,2

Then we can replace 1 by 1*2=2

so the sequence becomes 2,2

Then the minimum absolute difference between any two elements would be 2-2=0

Example 2: let the sequence is 5,8

then we can replace 5 by 10 or(and) 8 by 4.

But for minimum absolute difference we will replace 8 by 4.

So the answer would be 5-4 =1

I am not getting any idea. Can anybody please help me in this.

According to me, the answer always should be 0 or 1.

Comment: This is not clear.  It's easy to come up examples where you can get an absolute difference of $0$, but I expect that's not the answer you are looking for.  Perhaps an example would clarify things?

Comment: @lulu Added an example

Comment: Right, an example which proves that the absolute minimum is $0$.  So what's the problem?

Comment: @yfusav It will help if you either add more examples, with sequences with more than 2 numbers, or formulate the problem with more mathematical notation. The word order makes it ambiguous.

Comment: @lulu Given one more example.

Comment: Do you want the minimum as a function of the sequence?

Comment: @punctureddusk Yes

Comment: Well, with two elements, $a,b$ you might as well assume they are both odd.  Then, if $a<b$, we consider the greatest $n$ for which $2^na<b$, and look at the two differences $b-2^na$ and $2^{n+1}a-b$.  The answer will be one of those. No point looking at terms like $2^ma-2^nb$ since you could simply divide by $2^{\min(m,n)}$.

Comment: For instance, with your example we'd replace $8,5$ with $(a,b)=(1,5)$ for which $n=2$, since $2^2\times 1<5$ but $2^3\times 1 >5$.  We then compare $5-2^2\times 1=1$ with $2^3\times 1 -5=3$ and deduce that $1$ is minimal.

Answer (score 1):

0 e.g let number is E= 12 then E/2=6 and for E= 3 ,  2E=6 hence absolute difference is 0.

Comment: But if E's are different.

Comment: How can we generalise?

Comment: Are you talking about minimum between fixed given two or any two in a sequence of first n natural

Comment: Added one more example.

Comment: What do you mean I didn't get you on this

Comment: I have added two examples in my question.

Comment: Edited the question

Comment: In that manner consider 3 cases Case1. Numbers are (2n+1),2m.  Hence after transformation it will be (4n+2),m hence difference will be |2(2n+1)-m| which could be any whole number.$\\$ Case 2 . Numbers are 2n , 2m then after transformation it will be n,m hence difference is|n-m| which could be any natural number. $\\$ Case 3. Numbers are (2n+2),(2m+1) then after transformation it will be 2(2n+1) , 2(2m+1) hence difference will be 4|n-m| which is natural number multiply of 4.

Comment: Why you have edited it wrong.

Comment: |2(2n+1)-m| should  be smallest number.

Comment: Do you mean to say only one of number is transferred or both.

Comment: Because as the question reads is both transformation is done on every number in a seauence

Comment: We have choice to replace any number as many times(we may not replace it) we want.

Comment: It is not necessary to transform all the number.

Comment: Also after taking the difference the number should be smallest possible number.